# Who is the "woman" of Genesis 3:15?

Tags: genesis

According to the Hebrew, could/does the "woman" of Genesis 3:15 refer to Eve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Genesis 3:15** (KJV)
>   And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel.

It is the only woman that did not require the seed (sperm) from a man to reproduce (her seed). Totally implies virgin birth. Isaiah declares a virgin shall conceive 7:14.

Matthew declares it to be Mary:

> **Matthew 1:18** (KJV)
>   Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child of the Holy Ghost.

Comment: I do not see any direct connection between these three verses.

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew word הָאִשָּׁה (*ha-ishah*)—“the woman”—occurs nine times in Genesis 3.<sup>1</sup> It is doubtful that the occurrence in Genesis 3:15 refers to someone other than the referent of the other occurrences in the same chapter.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Gen. 3:1, 3:2, 3:4, 3:6, 3:12, 3:12 (x2), 3:15, 3:16

Comment: What are the referents? And is it possible that, grammatically, they could "refer to someone other"?

Comment: @Geremia—“What are the referents?”—Eve. That is the simple sense. If someone suggests הָאִשָּׁה refers to someone other than Eve, the onus is on them to prove it.

Comment: Yes, it would seem to refer to Eve, but why would there be enmity between her and the serpent? It would seem there would only be enmity between Eve and the serpent if Eve had resisted the serpant's temptations, but she succumbed, becoming the sepent's ally.

Comment: @Geremia—Are you Satan’s ally when you sin?

Comment: Perhaps "slave" to satan/sin is a better description.

Comment: Cf. Wisdom 2:24.

Answer (score 1):

Here she is:-

> NWT Revelation 12:13-17  "**Now when the dragon saw that it had been hurled down to the earth, it persecuted the woman who gave birth to the male child**. 14 But the two wings of the great eagle were given to the woman, so that she might fly into the wilderness to her place, where she is to be fed for a time and times and half a time away from the face of the serpent. 15 **And the serpent spewed out water like a river from its mouth after the woman**, to cause her to be drowned by the river. 16 But the earth came to the woman’s help, and the earth opened its mouth and swallowed up the river that the dragon spewed out from its mouth. 17 ***So the dragon became enraged at the woman and went off to wage war with the remaining ones of her offspring, who observe the commandments of God and have the work of bearing witness concerning Jesus."***

The Woman is God's heavenly organisation that Satan has hatred for so he attacks it supporters on earth.

In addition to the above for more on the meaning of "woman," and much more, go to:-

> Andrews University
>   Digital Commons @ Andrews University
>   Dissertations Graduate Research 2002
>   The Seed in Genesis 3:15 : an Exegetical and
>   Intertextual Study
>   From https://digitalcommons.andrews.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1115&context=dissertations

Comment: I'm looking more at it from a grammatical than an exegetical perspective.

Comment: @Geremis Try the above additional info.

Answer (score 0):

"Woman" occurs numerous times here and so must refer to Eve, but in this case to her seed.

The woman, Eve" appeared to have an unhealthy fascination with the serpent in the garden which, as a result, God decided to put enmity between the serpent and woman, specifically between the seed of woman and the seed of serpent.  This is clearly symbolic language and so we seek NT specific interpretations of this passage to understand it.

Gal 3:16 identifies Messiah Jesus as the seed of the woman.  John 8:42-47 identifies those who do not belong to God as having the devil as their father.

Thus, Gen 3:15 is a Messianic prophecy about the coming atonement via Jesus and Christ's suffering (bruising the heel) and the final destruction of the Satan and all his "children" (crushing the head).